# How to undo or reverse a Postfix postmap command

Tags: postfix

It's come to my attention that I might need to adjust my Postfix config in the following way to fix a mail delivery problem from one sender in particular:

```
# vim /etc/postfix/main.cf

+ header_checks = regexp:/etc/postfix/header_checks

# vim /etc/postfix/header_checks // NEW FILE

+ /^Delivered-To: .*/ IGNORE

# postmap /etc/postfix/header_checks
# service postfix restart
```

The part I'm uncomfortable with reversing is the `postmap` command.

The current plan to reverse this if it doesn't fix my problem is to just remove the `header_checks` line from main.cf and restart Postfix. Does that sound right?

My server has been running like a champ for 4+ years and I hate to mess with it when it's not necessary. Unfortunately it's necessary now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`postmap` creates a database file from the plain text input file. The exact name depends on the database type in use by your installation, but it will be something like `/etc/postfix/header_checks.lmdb`.

To stop using `header_checks` removing it from the config should be sufficient; to completely clean things up you can then delete both the source file and the generated database.

Comment: In my case on Debian, the file is `/etc/postfix/header_checks.db`. Many thanks!